What's wrong with my pseudo ranges?
I would like to figure out how to calculate pseudoranges from the information I receive in RTCM messages. The relevant fields of RTCM messages, if I understand correctly, are DF397, DF398, DF400. And I hope the formula for pseudorange measurement is:
P = (df397 * 1e6) + (df398 * (1e6 / 1024.0)) + df400

or like this.
But here are the typical values ​​of DF400 from one of my RTCM messages (message type 1074, that is, this is GPS):
DF400_01(010.1C)=0.00015116, DF400_02(010.2L)=0.00015587,
DF400_04(015.1C)=-0.00011706, DF400_05(015.2L)=-0.00012153,
DF400_07(018.1C)=-5.907e-05, DF400_08(018.2L)=-7.278e-05,
DF400_09(023.1C)=-0.00010216, DF400_10(023.2L)=-0.00011533,
DF400_11(026.1C)=0.0001992, DF400_12(026.2L)=0.00020641,
DF400_13(027.1C)=0.00011253, DF400_14(027.2L)=0.00010765,
DF400_15(029.1C)=-0.00038439, DF400_16(029.2L)=-0.0003795

For satellites 010, 026, 029, the DF400 values ​​for the 1C signal are less than for the 2L signal. For other satellites it’s the the opposite  way. But the difference is related to the ionospheric delay? And if so, then a signal with a high frequency should always have less ionospheric delay?
What's wrong here and how to evaluate pseudo range measurements?
My receivers are in the middle of nowhere - no houses, no tall buildings, no mountains; so I hope multipath is excluded.
